# How to copy the tables from one database to another database using SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-ce

I have two databases (SQL Server CE) that is one for Admin and other for Users

I have craeated an ASP.net membership for `Admin.sdf`. I don't want to copy membership tables from `Admin.sdf` to `User.Sdf`.

Please help me how to copy the remaining tables except the membership tables in SQL Server CE from code behind c#.

Comment: copy the db file and remove the specified table.

Comment: Couldn't the sql server integration service help you?

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response .i don't want copy the all files.Because,in User.sdf db having tables data but admin having only schema of tables only.when i copy the all tables then user.sdf will loose the data..

Comment: Then I would create a script for the specified tables. If you want to create the tables in the user db in your code, you need to execute the create queries one by one.

Comment: actually i have a default.sdf this default.sdf having the tables of schema.When the user login then automatically create new db with username and then copy the tables of schema from default.sdf.i added one more table in default.sdf that new table only copy into user.sdf Database

Comment: I think missing point is why do you want to do this? I hope this will help all of us to answer more precisely and correctly.